# Binary Tree in Python

Tags: python, binary-tree

This is my code-snippet for a Binary Tree implementation in Python. This WORKS when I run the PreOrder function.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data

class BinaryTree(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def addNode(self,data):
        return Node(data)

    def insert(self,root,data):
        if(root == None):
            root = self.addNode(data)
        else:
            if(data <= root.data):
               root.left = self.insert(root.left,data)
            else:
                root.right = self.insert(root.right,data)
        return root

    def PreOrder(self,root):
        if root == None:
            pass
        else:
            print(root.data)
            self.PreOrder(root.left)
            self.PreOrder(root.right)



a = BinaryTree()
root = a.addNode(2)
#root = None
a.insert(root,4)
a.insert(root,34)
a.insert(root,45)
a.insert(root,46)
a.insert(root,41)
a.insert(root,48)
a.PreOrder(root)
```

However changing the 2nd and the 3rd lines in main to

```
#root = a.addNode(2)
root = None
```

doesn't print anything. I feel I am missing out on something basic here. Any clarifications will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: You have a `self.root` attribute but never assign to it, then keep passing around an explicit `root`. Why not just do `self.root = ` and use `self.root` throughout?

Comment: Why do people keep telling Binary Tree where they really mean Binary Search Tree?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're passing `None` to your function, which you defined with:

```
if root == None:
    pass
```

That is why nothing gets printed.

Also, this is just a personal view, I would actually make PreOrder accept only the self argument, and do the PreOrder from there, making it very simple to define recursively.

Basically something like:

```
 def PreOrder(self):
     print self.data 
     if self.left:
          print self.left.PreOrder()
     if self.right:
          print self.right.PreOrder()
```

But this is a matter of preference, your solution works just fine.

As blatant promotion, I actually wrote a post about writing a basic BinaryTree in Python recently, if you care to check it out, it can be found here:

http://intothewebs.tumblr.com/post/40256328302/embrace-the-basics-binary-tree

UPDATE:

Ok, after you comment, I understand your doubt.

The root parameter that is passed into your method isn't really changed, because params in Python are passed by value:

[How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Read the accepted answer in this question, it's awesome and should explain what I mean by that.

Of you have:

```
root = None
a = a.insert(root,4)
a.insert...
```

And so forth, your code should work.

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt clear in the question. After changing to "root = None" I still have it followed by a.Insert(root,4) and so forth. So how is root none when I enter the PreOrder function?

Answer (score 1):

You have `root = None` and then in `PreOrder` your first line is `if root == None: pass` so it isn't going to do anything for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,data):
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.data = data

class BinaryTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None


    def insert_node(self,root,element):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(element)
        else:

            if root is None:
                root = Node(element)
            elif root.data <= element:
                root.right = self.insert_node(root.right,element)
            elif root.data > element:
                root.left = self.insert_node(root.left,element)


        return root

    def PreOrder(self,root):
        if root is not None:
            print(root.data)
            if root.left is not None:
                self.PreOrder(root.left)
            if root.right is not None:
                self.PreOrder(root.right)



a = BinaryTree()
a.insert_node(a.root,3)
a.insert_node(a.root,4)
a.insert_node(a.root,34)
a.insert_node(a.root,45)
a.insert_node(a.root,46)
a.insert_node(a.root,2)
a.insert_node(a.root,48)
a.PreOrder(a.root)
```